# Reading properties of hierarchical classes generically using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a set of classes that are generated via xsd.exe based on *.xsd files. Each set of classes generated for each set of *.xsd files are almost the same, except that there are a few  properties different in each class. For example, in both set 1 and set 2, Shape class might have different property.

I want to use a method to read the value of specified properties (**UPDATE**) of all classes in one set at a time (**Update**). There could be many levels of class. The method (e.g. `GetProperty` method) should only know about its parameter type, and the string representation of all properties. The method only read property.

Is there a better way of doing this:

```
    internal class DynPropertyTest
    {
        public static void Set1Test()
        {
            Shape shape = new Shape()
            {
                Name = "Shape",
                Shape2 = new Shape2()
                {
                   Name = "Shape2",
                   Shape3 = new Shape3() { Name = "Shape3" }
                }
            };

            GetProperty(shape);
        }

        public static void Set2Test() {
            ...
           }
```

**UPDATE**
  I would like to know an alternative way to achieve the similar function to the the method below

```
 //Should store all properties value in a collection, rather than display it
           //And somehow store/know the type of the property.
        public static void GetProperty(ShapeBase shape)
        {
            //shape.Name             


                Console.WriteLine(shape.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(shape, null));

            //Shape.Shape2
            object shape2 = shape.GetType().GetProperty("Shape2").GetValue(shape, null);
            Console.WriteLine(shape2);

            //Shape.Shape2.Name
            object shape2Name = shape.GetType().GetProperty("Shape2").PropertyType.GetProperty("Name")
                .GetValue(shape2, null);
            Console.WriteLine(shape2Name);

            //shape.shape2.shape3
            object shape3 = shape2.GetType().GetProperty("Shape3").GetValue(shape2, null);
            Console.WriteLine(shape3);

            //shape.shape2.shape3.Name
            object shape3Name = shape2.GetType().GetProperty("Shape3").PropertyType.GetProperty("Name")
                .GetValue(shape3, null);
            Console.WriteLine(shape3Name);
        }
    }

    abstract class ShapeBase { }

   //Example only. 
    namespace Set1
    {
        class Shape : ShapeBase
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Shape2 Shape2 { get; set; }
        }

        class Shape2
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Shape3 Shape3 { get; set; }
        }

        class Shape3
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }
    }

    namespace Set2
    {
        class Shape : ShapeBase{}
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how we implement this functionality (this is for getting a String value for dynamic SQL, but you should be able to apply it to your situation:

```
    public static string GetFieldValueForSQL(object oRecord, string sName)
    {
        PropertyInfo theProperty = null;
        FieldInfo theField = null;
        System.Type oType = null;

        try
        {
            oType = oRecord.GetType();

            // See if the column is a property in the record
            theProperty = oType.GetProperty(sName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public, null, null, new Type[0], null);
            if (theProperty == null)
            {
                theField = oType.GetField(sName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public);
                if (theField != null)
                {
                    return theField.GetValue(oRecord).ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return theProperty.GetValue(oRecord, null).ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception theException)
        {
            // Do something with the exception
            return string.empty;
        }
    }
```

**Update**

To process all of the properties, you can use code similar to this (note that this does not take into account IEnumerable implementors, but that should be fairly straightforward):

```
    public static void GetAllProperties(object oRecord)
    {
        System.Type oType = null;
        try
        {
            oType = oRecord.GetType();

            PropertyInfo[] cProperties;

            cProperties = oType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            foreach (PropertyInfo theProperty in cProperties)
            {
                if (theProperty.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    GetAllProperties(theProperty.GetValue(oRecord, null));
                }
                else
                {
                    // use theProperty.GetValue(oRecord, null).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception theException)
        {
            // Do something with the exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. In that case, just implement a recursive method where you GetProperties for the type that is specified and then for each type in that Type, GetProperties again. Will update with some pseudo code.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions of @competent, if you are concerned with performance you should  memoize the result of GetProperty(name) and then just use  propertyInfo.GetValue() on the record instances you are processing.

Comment: @Pingpong the provided sample definitely gives you enough to go off. Are you having a problem adapting it to your needs?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused: which specified property are you looking to read? And is this property the same in all of the nested classes?